# Use Jquery to show an element by its ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this is a simple question but I couldn't find the answer, I know you can use Jquery's show method on a class such as:

```
$('.class1').show();
```

But if I just want to call it on an element but not its entire class, for example with an id name of "am0" how do I do that? I tried:

```
$("am0").show();
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: `$("#am0").show();`

Comment: The reason you have to use '#' is because jQuery uses css selectors. '#' is used to select an element by its id. Without the '#', it just selects `<am0 ...></am0>` tags.

Comment: You can use all css selector types.  Here is a list http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put `#` in front of the id.

```
$("#am0").show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the ´#´ character to get an element by its id.

```
$("#am0").show();
```